# Doubt in a question on Continuity

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I came across the following problem in my reference book on Continuity. They defined a function $f(x) $ as follows:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x-2 & x\le0\\ 4-x^2 & x>0 \\ \end{cases}$$

Now, the book asked '*Discuss the continuity of $f(f(x))$*'.

Clearly, at $x = 0$, $f(x)$ is discontinuous as LHL $= f(0) = -2$ and RHL $= 4$ so RHL $\ne$ LHL.
Hence, for $f(f(x))$ to be discontinuous, $f(x) = 0$ so $x = 2$ is the only situation where $f(x) = 0$ so $x = 2$ is a solution.

Till here, I managed to solve the question. However, what stumped me was the fact that the book also gave $x = 0$ as a solution for which $f(f(x))$ is discontinuous stating the reason that 'If $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$, $f(f(x))$ is also discontinuous at $x = 0$, however, if I am to look at $f(f(0))$ it is equivalent to $f(-2)$ and $f(x)$ is clearly continuous at $x = -2$ as RHL $=$ LHL $= f(-2) = -4$.

Is there a reason that I am missing due to which $f(f(x))$ is discontinuous at $x = 0?$

Comment: No that was just a quote. 'Discuss the continuity of f(f(x))' is simply a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(f(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$ simply because as $x$ moves from $0^-$ to $0^+$, $f(x)$ goes from $-2$ to $4$, so $f(f(x))$ goes from having value $f(-2)=-4$ to $f(4)=-12$.

Comment: But if x = 0, f(x) is not lim x --> 0 f(0), it's quite literally = f(0) = -2. So why would the value range from -2 to 4 if the function is clearly defined at that point? If I define the function g(x) = [x] where [.] is greatest integer function and I ask you what is the value of g(0) the answer would be 0 not -1 or 0...

Comment: @Svee If you read closely, I said “ x goes from $0^-$ to $\color{red}{0^+}$”. Although there’s no change at $0$, there is an abrupt change just to the right of zero.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't seem to understand what you mean by 'x goes from 0- to 0+'. If we have to discuss the continuity exactly at x = 0 for f(f(x)) why would we consider 0- and 0+ to evaluate f(x). We would only consider the limits to evaluate f(f(x)) right?

Comment: @Svee Well, what does a limit mean? A limit is completely based on the values a function takes to the left and right of a point, and the exact point doesn’t matter. If you disregard what happens at $0^-$ and $0^+$, then surely any function which has $0$ in its domain is continuous, as $f(0)$ exists. Absurd.

Comment: Yes it is absurd if the function in discussion was f(x) [and you can see that I've clearly stated exactly what you did that f(x) is discontinuous at x = 0 in my question] however, the function we're discussing here isn't f(x) it's f(f(x)). It's like saying that if g(x) = f(f(x)) and f(x) = -2 for x <= 0 and f(x) = 1 for x > 0 and I ask you to evaluate g(0) you tell me the answer is -2 or 1 instead of just -2...

Comment: @Svee You need to get your question cleared up, first of all. You say ‘I ask you to evaluate $g(0)$’. Is that the question? If so, your question body asks whether $g$ is continuous at $0$. You’re going off track.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124832/discussion-between-svee-and-tavish).